# Removing an array/list of entries from google sheets by linking it to another workbook

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 different google sheets with different number of entries in each. I want entries from sheet 1(smaller one//the one below)which only has a single column of text with about 20 entires, to be compared to sheet 2, and then also remove the duplicates in the second sheet. I am attaching some sample images.
[image]

[image]

As can be seen- the image below has the list of all the people i want to exclude from the image above which has about 9000 entries in total.

All the solutions I found can only compare 2 sheets with cells in a very particular order. Is there a way for me to remove entries in sheets by "blacklisting" another list so as to remove the entries as soon as theres a duplication

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information)? Also, are you open to using Google Apps Script? If you want to remove existing rows from a sheet, that might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:Z, NOT(REGEXMATCH(C:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 IMPORTRANGE("url_of_blacklist_sheet here", blacklist_sheet_name!A:A)))))
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for getting back. I tried doing the exact same thing as you mentioned but am getting an error : "Error
No matches are found in FILTER evaluation." Could you please help

Comment: @Lauls0001 can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?